# examples of a function of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the value of $f \circ g(4)$, if $f:\rightarrow 3x - 1, x$ and $g: \rightarrow e^x/2, x$. I do understand what a function is but I need to understand the general method for this sort of problem.

Comment: is $fg$ the composition? plus, which one is supposed to be $f$ and which one is supposed to be $g$?

Comment: Be more precise: what is the domain of the functions? What does $fg(4)$ mean? Maybe $(f\circ g)(4)$?
You wrote two $f$... but I think the second is the $g$. Or not?

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake the correct question is:

Comment: I will try again, I am new to this site. Question is: I am trying to find the value of fg(4), if f:-> 3x -  1, x and g:-> e^x/2, x. I do understand what a function is but I need to understand the general method for this sort of problem.

Comment: your question doesn't make sense to me. what do you mean when you write f:-> 3x - 1, x? does your function $f$ maps $x$ to the pair $(3x-1, x)$...?

Comment: Thank you Joe, as you see spotted the second function should have read: g:-> e^x/2, x.

Answer (score 1):

First substitute $g(x)$ as the function given into $f(x)$

$f(g(x)) = f(\frac{e^x}{2})$.

Then, substitute $\frac{e^x}{2}$ into the $x$ of $f$.

$f(\frac{e^x}{2}) = 3(\frac{e^x}{2}) - 1 = \frac{3e^x}{2} - 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$f \circ g (4)$ means:  Compute $g(4)$, then take the result of that and feed it into $f$.

If you understand "what a function is" this should get you close enough to finish the problem on your own.